# use temporary table without future grant

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, future, sql-grant, temporary

I would like to get rid of Teamporary tables without having to issue FUTURE GRANT on my schema. The schema "DB_DEV.Schema" is a "WITH MANAGED ACCESS" schema.
But I do not succeed.
Here is the code of my tests.

Case 1

```
create or replace temporary table DB_DEV.Schema.TempTable as select cast(null as date) Col1 ,cast(null as date) as Col2 from Dual ;

select * from DB_DEV.Schema.TempTable ;

--SQL compilation error: Object 'DB_DEV.Schema."TempTable"' does not exist or not authorized.
```

Case 2

```
grant SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,TRUNCATE  ON future TABLES  IN SCHEMA DB_DEV.Schema  to  ROLE My_User_Role ;

create or replace temporary table DB_DEV.Schema.TempTable as select cast(null as date) Col1 ,cast(null as date) as Col2 from Dual ;

select * from DB_DEV.Schema.TempTable ;

--it works
```

Did I miss something or do something wrong?

Comment: Which role are you using when you create the table and which role are you using when you query the table?

Comment: Moin NickW, 
I use the My_User_Role role in both cases.

Comment: Who is showing as owner of the table?

Comment: I can't tell you that. It is a managed scheme. Also the SecurityAdmin or SYSAdmin can see the table in "My_DB". "INFORMATION_SCHEMA". "TABLES".